# Delete text on figure - Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, text, matlab-figure, subplot

I am trying to plot 2 animated figures in Matlab using subplots.

Everything is going well, except I have text on each plot containing the value of a variable that changes at each time step. Currently, the text is writing over the existing text on the plot.

How can I delete the text on the plot at each step so that I don't have this overwriting?

Thank you for your help!

```
Here is a simplistic example that highlights what I want to fix

for i = 1:.1:10
  subplot(1,2,1)
  axis([0 20 0 20])
  plot(i, i, '.')
  text(2,2,sprintf('i=%0.1f',i),'fontsize',10,'horizontalalign','center',...
      'verticalalign','middle')
  drawnow
  hold on
  subplot(1,2,2)
  axis([0 20 0 20])
  plot(i, i+1, 'o')
  text(2,2,sprintf('i=%0.1f',i+1),'fontsize',10,'horizontalalign','center',...
      'verticalalign','middle')
  drawnow
  hold on
  pause(0.01)
end
```

Comment: post some run-able code ... or ppl can just tell you to use Windows's Paint to remove the text ^_^

Comment: You can use `findobj(gca,'Type','Text')` and delete the handles of the text you don't want

Comment: This is a very simplistic example, but it highlights what I am trying to fix

Comment: for i = 1:.1:10
  subplot(1,2,1)
  axis([0 20 0 20])
  plot(i, i, '.')
  text(2,2,sprintf('i=%0.1f',i),'fontsize',10,'horizontalalign','center',...
      'verticalalign','middle')
  drawnow
  hold on
  subplot(1,2,2)
  axis([0 20 0 20])
  plot(i, i+1, 'o')
  text(2,2,sprintf('i=%0.1f',i+1),'fontsize',10,'horizontalalign','center',...
      'verticalalign','middle')
  drawnow
  hold on
  pause(0.01)
end

Comment: Awesome then glad to help!